# issue with play framework instance on my computer

Tags: playframework-1.x

I have tried using play 1.2.3 & 1.2.5 with the same code that was working on play 1.2.3 at a previous installation of ubuntu (using JDK7).  Now, I am getting class cast exceptions in my code (both with classes I wrote and third party libraries).  Should I switch to JDK6 or try something else?  I have already ran play clean (and the tmp directory was removed) but the issue is still outstanding.  I am using Sun JDK 7.

Update:  I reverted to JDK 6 but the class cast exceptions are still there (I used play clean as well - not sure if I am missing any further steps).  I have tried the application.conf with and without the 1.6 JDK reference.

Thank in advance.

Comment: So maybe you should concern on the bug instead writing that it doesn't work? It's really hard to guess what could cause the problem. Maybe memory?

Comment: the bug does not appear to be in my code (since the same code is running fine in test/demo/prod) - the code has not changed.  I am using the same third party libraries (& versions).  The app is not running out of memory - I have confirmed this.  I posted this question since others have had issues with play 1.2.3-1.2.5 & JDK 7 & I was wondering if anyone came across the same issue and was able to resolve this given the same setup.

Comment: did you run a "play deps" after upgrading to play 1.2.5. What are exactly the classes involved in the error ?

Comment: Thank you Seb for the suggestion - I tried it but it did not resolve the issue for me.  Once again, thanks for the suggestion as that is what makes this forum useful.  +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a classloader/multiple JDK issue - Eclipse was referencing JDK7 while I had switched over to JDK6 on the OS (without removing JDK 7).  Ensuring that eclipse (IDE) was referencing the default JDK (v6) fixed the issue.  Hope this helps others.